# How to import svn branch to git with trunk history

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn, version-control-migration

This is the svn `trunk` path:

```
http://svn/path/libs/trunk/mylib
```

And here is the `branch` path:

```
http://svn/path/libs/branches/mylib/mylib-feature-branch
```

I need to migrate only the branch to git, but I also need its trunk history before the branch was created.

The following command fetches only the branch history:

```
git svn clone http://svn/path/libs/branches/mylib/mylib-feature-branch
```

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169641/69537), but could not figure out how I should change the `git svn clone` command to have the full history of the branch.

Comment: Are you using this as one-time migration and then only git from there on, or do you want to use Git as frontend for the SVN server, committing back Git commits to the SVN server?

Comment: @Vampire This is going to be a one-time migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will easily be able to set up the rules file so that exactly your branch and its history will get migrated.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though git-svn is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same `svn_dirent_join: Assertion svn_dirent_is_canonical(base, pool) failed.` error as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770736/svn2git-object-reference-error#comment64942888_38784776). Unfortunately the solution on the github has been deleted. Could you please tell me what was the problem?

Comment: oh, I think I need to run commands directly on the svn server, right?

Comment: As the documentation says, you have to have a local copy of the SVN directory. Whether you download the repo to your local box or execute `svn2git` on the SVN server does not matter much.

Comment: And why do you say the solution was deleted on GitHub? The first comment bears the solution.

Comment: Do you know how I can download the repo to my local box? I cannot seem to find the command.

Comment: The first comment on that post is "Let's try it then... ". I think you meant another comment bears the solution.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. You said the solution was deleted on GitHub and I said this is wrong, the first comment on that GitHub issue bears the solution (not the first comment on SO ;-)) If you have access to the SVN server box, just use any file copying tool like SFTP, RSYNC, SCP or whatever. If not, you can still use something like `rsvndump` as shown in the documentation of svneverever that I also linked in the answer: https://github.com/hartwork/svneverever

Comment: Well, there was probably a github server problem that I could not open the page couple of hours ago. I can see it now, thanks :) let me give it a try...

Comment: I finally got it working and everything migrated smoothly as I needed. Thanks a lot dude!